# Few Questions about Threading, COM+ and STA apartments

Tags: multithreading, delphi, com+, sta

I have a windows service which creates 10 threads + the one which creates the tasks list.

Each of these 11 threads enters STA by calling CoInitialize(nil).

1. Tasks list is created by one thread, other get the item, process it and free ....

a) Can the other thread use the object created by the other thread?
(Thats seems to work, but ..)
b) Can the other thread free the memory allocated by the other thread? 
(Thats seems to not work...)

Should I somehow marshal the pointer between threads?
Or should I at least get the item, process it, but let it be freed be the "owner" of the thread which created it?

1. In my windows services I created the functionality which I can use to start/stop the services(suspand and resume the threads).

However I have a problem with the thread which actually collects the data and does it in the interval.
When the thread loads the items to process, then after it, it enters sleep state for 5 minutes.
How can i terminate such thread safely? How to abort sleep state?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to marshall interfaces across threads. [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/206076) you can find a C++ example, and the same articles shows the three techniques you can use (oMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream/CoMarshalInterface/Global Interface Table(GIT)). More information about them you can find in MSDN.

To have a thread wait but being able to terminate it before the sleep ends, use WaitForSingleObject() with a proper timeout value and for example a Windows event to wait for. When the functions exit it will tell if it exited because the timeout elapsed or the event was set. To exit the wait function before the timeout is reached simnply set the event. Thereby you can choose if to enter another wait loop or exit.

Comment: From the application example i read:

"If you create a COM object in one STA thread, you cannot pass an interface pointer to another STA thread and call out on that pointer. If you try, you will get an error HRESULT of 0x8001010E or RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD(The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread)."

does it mean that only com objects must be marshalled?
What about common instances of the classes which derive from TObject?

Comment: It depends on what you use and how you create it. Everything COM-related must adhere to COM rules. What is not under COM control doesn't. So if you have a plain Delphi class instance you can pass it and use it across different threads and use "classic" concurrency techniques to protect access to them. If you're going to use COM objects (and probably you're using some, if you're calling CoInitialize) you have to manage their interfaces correctly to pass them among threads. Beware, anyway, of Delphi classes that inside wraps a COM object (i.e. TXMLDocument when used with MSXML)

Answer (score 2):

To marshall  an STA object pointer between STA threads use `CoMarshallInterThreadInterfaceInStream`, and `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream`.

An STA thread MUST pump messages, as that is how STA threads use COM, using windows messages. I.e. you must call GetMessage/TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage. Probably your framework has a simple message pump function you could use to do this.

To abort your sleep state of 5 minutes, do multiple sleeps for shorter intervals, and check a "shouldquit" flag. Set the shouldquit flag in the Service Main.

Comment: Ad1. I know that such method exists, but I am rather curious if it is neccessary between two threads.
Ad2. I know that is the solution, but because I am always trying to do "wait operations" without not necessery processor cykles like loops, etc. And That's the reason why I was curious if the sleep or something could be programically interrupted to let the thread gracefully finished its job.

Comment: Yes it is absolutely neccesary between two threads. It will create a proxy which takes care of the threading/locking issues on each call.
Also, an STA thread MUST pump messages, so you cannot sleep. You should be doing a message pump not sleeping. A message pump will sleep when it can anyway.

Comment: 1. Why then, delphi allows me to retrieve and use the object created by the other thread? 
2. So Does it mean, that objects being passed between threads must derive from specific Interface. And when it is "unmarshalled" (with CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream) the instance of the object should be freed: in the thread where it was created and also in the thread which used CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream?

Comment: 1. COM will do a lot for you if you keep to the rules, but you can always choose break them. Delphi is a language which will allow you to shoot yourself in the foot if you are determined to. 2. Delphi will (probably) take care of that for you as long as you stick to the COM interfaces. 2b. Objects in COM are reference counted. It needs to be `Release`d once for every time it was `AddRef`ed. The proxy object retrieved from `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` must be released from the thread from which it was retrieved.

Comment: Delphi interfaced objects are not dependant on COM.  If you do not create an instance of an interfaced object using COM's CoCreateInstance/Ex() function, then your inter-thread access of that object is not limited by COM's marshaling rules.